# Sharding a Django Project

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sharding

I'm starting a Django project and need to shard multiple tables that are likely to all be of too many rows. I've looked through threads here and elsewhere, and followed the Django multi-db documentation, but am still not sure how that all stitches together. My models have relationships that would be broken by sharding, so it seems like the options are to either drop the foreign keys of forgo sharding the respective models.

For argument's sake, consider the classic Authot, Publisher and Book scenario, but throw in book copies and users that can own them. Say books and users had to be sharded. How would you approach that? A user may own a copy of a book that's not in the same database.

In general, what are the best practices you have used for routing and the sharding itself? Did you use Django database routers, manually selected a database inside commands based on your sharding logic, or overridden some parts of the ORM to achive that?

I'm using PostgreSQL on Ubuntu, if it matters.

Many thanks.

Comment: Seems like premature optimization to me. How do you know your service is going to grow so much?

Comment: I don't know that, but I have to plan for that. For tables larger than a certain number, it becomes very costly to select from, and even more so to update (especially if indexed). If I don't shard from the beginning, at least logically, it'll be harder to do it later. Do you disagree?

Answer (score 4):

In the past I've done something similar using Postgresql [Table Partitioning](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-partitioning.html), however this merely splits a table up in the same DB.  This is helpful in reducing table search time.  This is also nice because you don't need to modify your django code much.  (Make sure you perform queries with the fields you're using for constraints).

But it's not sharding.

If you haven't seen it yet, you should check out [Sharding Postgres with Instagram.](http://www.databasesoup.com/2012/04/sharding-postgres-with-instagram.html)

Comment: Thanks, Monkut. Partitioning will allow me to scale to some point, but I need to go beyond. I was aware that the guys at Instagram are using a similar stack, but have not seen this video, so I'm very happy you added that note. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @DanielRoseman.  Also, how many is too many rows.  If you are careful with indexing, you can handle a lot of rows with no performance problems.  Keep your indexed values small (ints).  I've got tables in excess of 400 million rows that produce sub-second responses even when joining with other many million row tables.

It might make more sense to break user up into multiple tables so that the user object has a core of commonly used things and then the "profile" info lives elsewhere (std Django setup).  Copies would be a small table referencing books which has the bulk of the data.  Considering how much ram you can put into a DB server these days, sharding before you have too seems wrong.

Comment: Hi Mark. Thanks for your detailed answer. I definitely agree that optimizing before you need to is wrong. In regards to "copies", I was trying to say that that, too, will be a large table, larger than "books".